# Xcode 8 IPA file not supporting for iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, cpu-architecture, iphone-5, armv7

I'm developing an app using Xcode 8.0, which needs to have a support from iPhone 5. I'm using the valid architecture and standard architecture as armv7s and arm64. But the archived build is not supporting for iPhone 5. I'm attaching the screenshot showing the supported devices below.

[image]

I know iPhone 5 is using A6 processor and armv7s does support to A6 processor, but I dont know why iPhone 5 is not listing in the compatible device list.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that your standard architecture includes the armv7s like so [image]

afterwards the iPhone 5 will appear in the list

[image]

Comment: How you added armv7s as standard architecture?

Comment: You can just place `armv7s` behind `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`

Comment: Now I'm getting a compiler error: ARM_RELOC_SECTDIFF missing following pair file '/Users/macmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleApp-eeagbtfxwuuhqkarwzifpebnbrhk/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SampleApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SampleApp.build/Release-iphoneos/SampleApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Parser.o' for architecture armv7s

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S have you tried deleting the project derived data folder ?

Comment: Yes, also I found that Parser.o file is there inside the armv7s folder inside the Object-normal

Comment: @VishnuKumar.S sorry i haven't faced the same issue when trying the same setup, so i will deleted my answer.

Comment: Its Ok, no need to delete your answer, it may help someone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128716/discussion-between-vishnu-kumar-s-and-abd-al-rhman-taher-badary).